# Passing parent's scope to a child instance

Tags: javascript, oop, scope

I've built a presentation player that creates its slides as iframes and I'm trying to clean up my code now that I have the prototype working. I'm having issues finding the best way to handle the interaction between the slides and the presentation player, though. The slides need to do things like tell the player that they have loaded or that they have finished playing.

I made a simplified example of the interaction the player and slide instances need to have...

```
  function Parent() {
    this.child = undefined;
    this.makeChild = function() {
      this.child = new Child(this);
    };
    this.payAttention = function(message) {
      console.log('Child says, "' + message + '"');
    };
  }

  function Child(parent) {
    this.getAttention = function() {
      parent.payAttention('I\'m hungry.');
    };
  }

  var dad = new Parent();
  dad.makeChild();
  dad.child.getAttention();
```

This pattern is working, but I'm wondering if this is the most efficient way to handle this. Is there a better way to do this, or is this okay?

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable for a child to have a reference to their parent as part of their instance data.  What you are doing is fine and there is no particular better way to do it.

Comment: You could put child into an anonymous function wich saves a few lines...

Comment: Seems fine. An alternative is to just pass callbacks to the child instead of an object with a `payAttention` method. Or for less coupling, use a mediator.

Answer (score 0):

You could save a few lines with inserting an object to the variable:

```
this.child={};
this.makeChild=function(){
a=function(){
this.payAtention("Im Hungry");
}
a.bind(this);
this.child.getAttention=a;
}
```

If you never dealt with *.bind(scope)*:
Bind binds the object passed as the parameter to the this inside the function.

By the way, if there are multiple childs:

```
this.child=[];
this.child.push({name:"Tim"});
```